# MediaRecorder audio playback speed

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am developing call recording app. I used MediaRecorder to record calls. Playback speed of recorded files is **very high** and **cannot understand**. but when I play it slow motion(30%-50% speed) using KMPlayer it can understand clearly. This happened **only with outgoing calls and only in samsung galaxy core 2**. Below is my code.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

source code to identify outgoing call is below and according to that call the `startRecording()` method which include above code snippet.

```
else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
   if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
      outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
      absPath = startRecording("-OUT-");
        if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
        state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
          if (state != null) {
             if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                wasRinging = false;
                if (recordstarted) {
                   try{
                       recorder.stop();
                       recordstarted = false;
                       }catch (Exception e){
                         Log.e(TAG,"IOException",e);
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

Any solution accept in advance.

Answer (score 1):

remove this two line

```
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
```